# Acceleration in ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an app that processes location updates when the user is moving in a car.I need to get the acceleration as well as braking events from the app.
I use the "freeway drive option" in the simulator to simulate motion of a car.

If I switch from "freeway drive" to "city run" I am able to get braking events, but vice versa I cant get acceleration.
Does anyone know how I can get acceleration events ?

Comment: once I had a similar situation with other sensor and I was faking returning values in delegate methods so the user thought it was working normally